# Eloquent WHERE NOT with relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am using Lumen and it's Models with model's relationships. What I am trying to do is to get all Categories and count how many posts every category has, which is working fine. However, I do not want it to count those which `creator_id == $current_user_id`, how should I do it?

This is in my Post class:

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

And this is in my Category class:

```
public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

And this is my query:

```
public function getCategories($user_id){
        $categories = Category::withCount('posts')->get();
        return new JsonResponse(['categories' => $categories]);
}
```

So I do not want to count posts that the current user has created.

So the output should be something like this:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "name": "All",
            "posts_count": 0
        }]
}
```

This what I also tried without success:

```
$categories = Category::where('creator_id', '!=', $user_id)->withCount('posts')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following line:

```
$categories = Category::withCount(['posts' => function($query) use($user_id){
   $query->where('creator_id', '!=', $user_id);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work. But is it safe to use it like this? I saw in some Laracast's forum post that you shouldn't do it like that. I might be wrong, correct me if I am.

Comment: Feel free to use this method. It is the right way to do this